# How to measure ARM64 branch size?

Tags: xcode

I got an error like below when building the application. However, I don't know the actual size as it doesn't occur with some code optimization settings.

```
ld: b(l) ARM64 branch out of range (153544076 max is +/-128MB): from +[UnityURLRequest storeRequest:taskID:] (0x00004670) to __Unwind_Resume@0x00000000 (0x09272CCC) in '+[UnityURLRequest storeRequest:taskID:]' from /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-ddznnkuubjszymahzwwsyvhwlyin/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Unity-iPhone.build/Debug-iphoneos/UnityFramework.build/Objects-normal/arm64/UnityWebRequest.o
```

Also, this module is generated by Unity and is uncontrollable.

We can cut our module and avoid the error, but I would like to know how much to cut and how much more room is left for future development.

I tried a normal build and expected the build to succeed without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

It's a Unity project.

^_^

This problem always occur Unity project to a xcode project.
unity project though il2cpp to create a xcode project .
In this place , the xcode project build will have Text__text and TEXT__il2cpp. if bl from il2cpp to text or text to il2cpp . if bl branch across above 128mb. will tip you error info

you can solve like follow actions:

1. Open Unity Strip Level. And turn it to high. strip symbols size
2. Solve Text_text section length from xcode build setting - other link flags . use "-wl xxx"

Comment: 3. Try to update you Xcode build toolchain to improve build performance

Comment: 4. Try to delete some unuse depency librarys

Comment: 5. Change you xcodebuild command line , if you don't need debug , change configuration to Release 。 this might resolve problem

Comment: 6. change some statiic library to dynamic library